# R Shiny App: Size Plot Area with Input from renderPlot expr

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to alter the height of a shiny plot area according to some object created in the `renderPlot` `expr`.

Here is a simple example that *almost* does what I need. This sizes the window as a function of session characteristics:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot1", height="auto")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
    }, height = function() {
      session$clientData$output_plot1_width
    })
  }
))
```

However, instead of sizing the plot area as a function of the session characteristics, I would like to size it based on something I calculate within the `renderPlot` expression (`renderPlot({})`), like this:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot1", height="auto")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
    }, height = length(unique(cars$speed)))
  }
))
```

In this case I am creating `l` within `renderPlot`'s expression and then trying to use `l` to size the plot area outside of the expression.

Thanks for any leads!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `renderUI/uiOutput` to dynamically set the height of the plot, using `reactiveValues` to transfer the value from the `renderPlot`:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(uiOutput("ui1")),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    my <- reactiveValues(l = 500)

    output$ui1 <- renderUI(plotOutput("plot1", height=my$l))

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      my$l <- length(unique(cars$speed))*100
      plot(cars)
    })
  }
))
```